# Futures in Dart / flutter_sound examples not working

Tags: flutter, dart, async-await

Start tinkering with Dart/Flutter, I'm trying to record and play audio. Examples provided in this library: https://github.com/dooboolab/flutter_sound show async code in Dart using Futures.

```
Future<String> result = await flutterSound.startRecorder(null);

result.then(path) {
    print('startRecorder: $path');

    _recorderSubscription = flutterSound.onRecorderStateChanged.listen((e) {
    DateTime date = new DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(e.currentPosition.toInt());
    String txt = DateFormat('mm:ss:SS', 'en_US').format(date);
    });
}
```

However this code doesn't even compile at my system so Im wondering what I'm missing. In order to compile this code I have to change it to something like:

```
Future<String> result = widget._flutterSound.startRecorder(null);

result.then((path) {
  print('startRecorder: $path');

  var _recorderSubscription = widget._flutterSound.onRecorderStateChanged.listen((e) {
    DateTime date = new DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(e.currentPosition.toInt());
    print(date);
  });
});
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Have you try this:

```
Future<String> result() async => flutterSound.startRecorder(null);
```

when you working with futures: async and await: https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await

> The **async** and **await** keywords provide a declarative way to define asynchronous functions and use their results. Remember these two basic guidelines when using **async** and **await**:
>
> - To define an async function, add **async** before the function body.
> - The **await** keyword works only in **async** functions.